# How can I calculate the length of string produced in a varargs function in C?

Tags: c, string, variadic-functions, string-length

Suppose I have a call to `printf` that will print the name of a file whose length can only be determinate at runtime:

```
//"buff" gets the name of the file
printf("Name of the file is: %s",buff);
```

What I would like to know is how can I calculate the length of the final string. In my example above, if the name of the file is "file.txt", this value would be 29. I need this because I need to create a buffer whose size shall match the length of the string it's going to get and this inside a function that uses varargs:

```
void general_printfL(__const char *__restrict __format, ...)
{
    char buffy[final_size_of__format];

    //Do something...
}
```

I tried using `sizeof(char) * strlen(__format)` for the code above, but the segmentation faults I got indicated me this isn't an appropriate way of calculating the final string's length. I also couldn't find anything useful on Google about this.

Comment: use snprintf and it will return how many characters you need.  Then allocate the buffer and call snprintf again with the returned size

Comment: You can use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for this.

Comment: Use the return value of `printf()`  --> `int len = printf("Name of the file is: %s",buff);`

Comment: `snprintf` is what you need. But if you are using a GNU C library, `asnprintf` will do the trick in one go (it allocates using `malloc()` on the heap).

Comment: @bruceg your method worked; I did `char bufTemp[1]; const int reqBuffSize = snprintf(bufTemp,0,__format); char buff[reqBuffSize + 5];` and so forth. If you don't mind, you may write this as an answer to the question so I may select it.

Comment: @abligh I found you suggestion interesting. Could you please write it as an answer with a code example? At least you'll get an up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the GNU C library, it already has a function that does exactly this, passing arguments either as varargs (`asprintf`) or as a `va_list` (`vasprintf`). The resultant buffer is allocated on the heap, and must be freed with `free()`.

```
ASPRINTF(3)                 Linux Programmer's Manual                ASPRINTF(3)

NAME
       asprintf, vasprintf - print to allocated string

SYNOPSIS
       #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
       #include <stdio.h>

       int asprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, ...);

       int vasprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, va_list ap);

DESCRIPTION
       The  functions  asprintf()  and vasprintf() are analogs of sprintf(3) and
       vsprintf(3), except that they allocate a string large enough to hold  the
       output  including  the terminating null byte ('\0'), and return a pointer
       to it via the first argument.  This pointer should be passed  to  free(3)
       to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.

RETURN VALUE
       When successful, these functions return the number of bytes printed, just
       like sprintf(3).  If memory allocation wasn't  possible,  or  some  other
       error occurs, these functions will return -1, and the contents of strp is
       undefined.
```

Example code would be as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *output = NULL;
  char *param1 = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "foo";
  char *param2 = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : "bar";

  if (asprintf (&output, "Hello from %s and %s\n", param1, param2) < 0)
    {
      perror ("asprintf");
      exit (1);
    }

  printf ("%s", output);

  free (output);
  exit (0);
}
```

The buffer `output` is allocated to be the size of the required string.

If you want to pass what you are passed to your function as varargs to another function, use something like:

```
int
general_printfL(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  int ret;
  va_start (ap, fmt);
  char *output = NULL;
  ret = vasprintf (&output, fmt, ap);
  va_end (ap);
  if (ret<0)
    return ret;
  /* ... your code here ... */
  free (output);
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
buflen = 1 + snprintf(buffy, 1, "Name of the file is: %s", buff);
buffy = malloc(buflen * sizeof char);
snprintf(buffy, buflen, "Name of the file is: %s", buff);
```